# implement tls.Config.GetCertificate with self signed certificates

Tags: http, ssl, go

I m trying to figure out how i can implement a function to feed to `tls.Config.GetCertificate` with self signed certificates.

I used this bin source as a base, https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

Also read this,
https://ericchiang.github.io/tls/go/https/2015/06/21/go-tls.html

Unfortunately, so far i m stuck with this error
`2016/11/03 23:18:20 http2: server: error reading preface from client 127.0.0.1:34346: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority`

I think i need to generate a CA cert and then sign the key with it, but i m not sure how to proceed (....).

Here is my code, can someone help with that ?

```
package gssc

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "math/big"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func GetCertificate(arg interface{}) func(clientHello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
    var opts Certopts
    var err error
    if host, ok := arg.(string); ok {
        opts = Certopts{
            RsaBits:   2048,
            Host:      host,
            ValidFrom: time.Now(),
        }
    } else if o, ok := arg.(Certopts); ok {
        opts = o
    } else {
        err = errors.New("Invalid arg type, must be string(hostname) or Certopt{...}")
    }
    return func(clientHello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return generate(opts)
    }
}

type Certopts struct {
    RsaBits   int
    Host      string
    IsCA      bool
    ValidFrom time.Time
    ValidFor  time.Duration
}

func generate(opts Certopts) (*tls.Certificate, error) {

    priv, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, opts.RsaBits)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to generate private key")
    }

    notAfter := opts.ValidFrom.Add(opts.ValidFor)

    serialNumberLimit := new(big.Int).Lsh(big.NewInt(1), 128)
    serialNumber, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, serialNumberLimit)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to generate serial number\n")
    }

    template := x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: serialNumber,
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Organization: []string{"Acme Co"},
        },
        NotBefore: opts.ValidFrom,
        NotAfter:  notAfter,

        KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageKeyEncipherment | x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
    }

    hosts := strings.Split(opts.Host, ",")
    for _, h := range hosts {
        if ip := net.ParseIP(h); ip != nil {
            template.IPAddresses = append(template.IPAddresses, ip)
        } else {
            template.DNSNames = append(template.DNSNames, h)
        }
    }

    if opts.IsCA {
        template.IsCA = true
        template.KeyUsage |= x509.KeyUsageCertSign
    }

    derBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, &template, &template, &priv.PublicKey, priv)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to create certificate")
    }

    return &tls.Certificate{
        Certificate: [][]byte{derBytes},
        PrivateKey:  priv,
    }, nil
}
```

This is the test code i use

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "github.com/mh-cbon/gssc"
    "net/http"
)

type ww struct{}

func (s *ww) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.Write([]byte("This is an example server.\n"))
}

func main() {
    s := &http.Server{
        Handler: &ww{},
        Addr:    ":8080",
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
            GetCertificate:     gssc.GetCertificate("example.org"),
        },
    }
    s.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't use `go fmt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of `tls.Config.GetCertificate` is causing the problem.

You are generating a certificate each time `tls.Config.GetCertificate` is called. You need to generate the certificate once and then return it in the anonymous function.

In `gssc.GetCertificate` :

```
cert, err := generate(opts)

return func(clientHello *tls.ClientHelloInfo) (*tls.Certificate, error) {
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return cert, err
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for feedback, really appreciated, unfortunately it really does not help me as i previously did use that code to create a [binary](https://github.com/mh-cbon/sscg) tool generate those certificates as plain file, so i knew it was working. I m really looking to implement this GetCert method in the same fashion as [this](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert). Maybe i should have precised in my original post.

Comment: Updated. I'm guessing this is the issue.

Comment: Yeah! I see the problem now, i was generating a new cert every time so the browser was mixing up when the subsequent requests were coming into. I still have the error `2016/11/09 11:18:36 http2: server: error reading preface from client 127.0.0.1:41748: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority`, but this is a problem for another question i guess. Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting `Certopts.IsCA` as `true`, in your config ?

Comment: I was not, you are right again!!! : ) i ll be able to pack it in a package now. Many thanks!